# Use JWT authentication in asp.net mvc 5 razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jwt

I use JWT for authentication in my **asp.net mvc 5** application. I can implement token generation and token validation but I want to find a way to use JWT validation in my razor pages, Something like `@User.Identity.IsAuthenticate` when you use identity.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: [flowing two discussions might be of help ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095076/custom-authentication-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: [following two discussions might be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54808415/use-web-api-jwt-authentication-inside-razor-pages-application?noredirect=1&lq=1)